# Distribution of residue classes of totients of (univariate) polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $\phi$ denote Euler's totient function and $f$ a non-constant univariate polynomial with integer coefficients such that $f(u) \in \mathbf N^+$ for all $u \in \mathbf N^+$ (assume $f$ is irreducible if useful/necessary).

> **Q1.** Is it true that $\mathfrak i_f := \inf_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n}|\phi(f(u)) \bmod n: u \in \mathbf N^+\}| > 0$?

We have from [[1](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper116.pdf)] that if a residue class (modulo a fixed $n \in \mathbf N^+$) contains at least one multiple of 4 then it contains infinitely many totients (i.e., stuff in the image of $\phi$), which implies that the answer to Q1 is affirmative if $f$ is linear and monic. In fact, I would be already happy to hear about other particular cases. So let me add the following:

> **Q2.** What about the case when $f$ is linear/quadratic?

My motivation (for those here who dislike random questions) is somehow related to the study of the "density" (whatever this means) of sets of totients.

**Bibliography.**

[[1](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper116.pdf)] T. Dence and C. Pomerance, *Euler's Function in Residue Classes*, Ramanujan J. **2** (1998), 7-20 ([click](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper116.pdf)).

Comment: I doubt you can prove something like that unconditionally.

Comment: The answer, if positive, would resolve a "long standing" math.stack question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43020/all-polynomials-with-no-natural-roots-and-integer-coefficients-such-that-phin

Comment: I doubt it too, but special cases (I mean, cases corresponding to some specific choice of $f$) would already be interesting to me. E.g., what about the linear/quadratic case? (Btw, thanks for the link.)